# how to create a static library or framework from a already available source code in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, static-libraries

My clients wants to use some of the already available features in my app into their app. But, i dont want to share my source code with them and vice versa. I found out from some googling that, we can do this by creating some static libraries or frameworks in iOS. Can anyone throw some light on how to create a static library or framework (which ever is better) out of my already available source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ton of thanks to Diney Bomfim for his [excellent article](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/#list_contents) on how to create a framework. This is exactly what i am looking for.

EDIT - **The Link is NOT working anymore...**

Answer (score 4):

My preference is to use static libraries over Frameworks. You will provide your customers the library file (.a extension) and the header file(s) for the functions in it. They just need to install the files somewhere in their project tree, set the include path, add the library to the project and they are good to go.

Note that if you want them to use your lib in the Simulator as well as on device you will need to provide them two versions of the library, one for each.

For instructions on how to create and use an iOS static library see [this site](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/).

Comment: +1 for some nice description Miguel. I'l go through the link and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: This is not a correct answer because in .a files the source can be easily extracted , so he practically shared all his source with them.

Comment: @James: you are incorrect. Static libraries contain object code, not source code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information:

I created a static framework for iOS according to [jverkoey's instruction](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)